# Python Regex: negative lookbehind not directly before target word

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I am building an NLP baseline script in Jupyter Notebook that should filter out all 'embolisms' from reports. However, when the word 'no' or 'not' occur in the same line/sentence, I do not want them included. This is easy with regex, once you know where the word will occur, if it occurs. But there can be many words in between.

- Example: The scan has shown an embolism present; should be included
- Example: No embolism has been found; should be excluded (this is easy with Regex)
- Problem example: Currently no developing, interesting, nice, beautiful embolism has been found; should be excluded, but I have no idea how.

This is the regex for excluding the 'no embolism' when they are together in the sentence:

```
result = re.findall('(?<!\no )(embolism?\w)', text)
```

The error occurring with regular regex when extending to multiple words is: "error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern"

I have googled on how to solve it, but I did not find a solution applicable to this problem. I did also find that installing Regex with pip removes the aforementioned error. However, I'm still wondering whether there is a solution for this problem?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the last 2 by matching them, and capture the first example that you want to keep in a group.

```
^(?:.*\bnot?\b.*\bembolism\b.*|.*\bembolism\b.*\bnot?\b.*)|(.*\bembolism\b.*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `.*\bnot?\b.*\bembolism\b.*` Match first no or not followed by embolism
  - `|` Or
  - `.*\bembolism\b.*\bnot?\b.*` Match it the other way around
- `)` Close non capture group
- `|` Or
- `(.*\bembolism\b.*)` Capture **group 1** (what you want to keep) containing embolism
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2gNu0d/1)

Comment: Thank you! I did not fully understand the possibilities of \b...\b yet. The grouping part of regex is also more clear now.

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary, that prevents the "word" being part of a larger word. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html